# throw a timeout exception after a period of time

Tags: php

I am working with this php script. Basically it uses the command shell_exec to run a javascript crawler. And when it works, it returns a string. However, sometimes the js crawler becomes unresponsive and shell_exec just hangs.

I want to be able to wrap the shell_exec in a try catch, and after 60 seconds execute the catch and just gracefully handle it, so that shell_exec no longer hangs indefinitely.

```
try {
    $output = shell_exec($input);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '60 seconds passed and response is: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

I am not sure what command I have available in PHP to essentially say "let's try to run this command for 60 seconds and if it exceeds that time, then let's throw an exception and handle that exception instead."

Answer (score 0):

`shell_exec()` is a blocking function, meaning it blocks the script from continuing.

If you have control of the executible it is running, you could do `shell_exec("nohup $input &");` and have it write some defined output files and status files, then have a PHP while loop with a `sleep(n)` that waits for either of those to appear, or for time to run out.

There are other functions available which give more fine-grained control, like `proc_open()`, but it is not very familiar to me so I'm not exactly sure how to leverage them to create a timeout exception.